# Backbone testing render view with Jest - Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined

Tags: unit-testing, backbone.js, jestjs, render, marionette

I am trying to write a very simple unit test with Jest for a Backbone/Marionette view.

Code of the test :

```
import MyView from './MyView';

describe('test of my view', function() {
  const myView = new MyView().render();
});
```

But that return the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'createDocumentFragment' of undefined`.

```
at buildFragment (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:4311:22)
  at domManip (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5238:14)
  at jQuery.fn.init.append (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5431:10)
  at jQuery.fn.init.<anonymous> (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5525:18)
  at access (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3642:7)
  at jQuery.fn.init.html (node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:5492:10)
  at Marionette.TemplateCache.loadTemplate (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1169:24)
  at Marionette.TemplateCache.load (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1149:27)
  at Function.get (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1111:29)
  at Object.render (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1200:87)
  at child._renderTemplate (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1664:38)
  at child.render (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:1632:12)
  at child.render (node_modules/backbone.marionette/lib/core/backbone.marionette.js:2628:51)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/js/my.view.spec.js:22:27)
```

I am not sure how I can fix that as my view is pretty dumb (output hardcoded html) and problem seems to be more on backbone/marionette/jquery side than in my view code.

The MyView code (simplified to one button, but it's just duplication for many buttons) :

```
import Marionette from 'backbone.marionette';

import { LeftMenuView as LeftMenuViewTemplate } from './templates.index';

const LeftMenuView = Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    template: LeftMenuViewTemplate,

    ui: {
        generalButton: '.menu-general',
        generalLink: '.menu-general-link',
    },
    buttonsList: [
        'generalButton',
    ],
    events: {
    '    click @ui.generalLink': 'switchToGeneral',
    },

    initialize() {},

    onShow() {
        this.ui.navLine.height(this.ui.generalButton.innerHeight());
        this.ui.navLine.css('top', this.ui.generalButton.position().top);
    },

    _animate(target) {
        const topPos = target.position().top;
        const newHeight = target.innerHeight();
        this.ui.navLine.stop().animate({
            top: topPos,
            height: newHeight,
        });
    },

    setInactiveButtons() {
        for (let i = 0; i < this.buttonsList.length; i += 1) {
            this.ui[this.buttonsList[i]].toggleClass('active', false);
        }
    },

    switchToGeneral() {
        this.setInactiveButtons();
        this.ui.generalButton.toggleClass('active', true);
        this.trigger('changePage:toGeneral');
        this._animate(this.ui.generalButton);
    },

});

export default LeftMenuView;
```

And the associated template code (handlebar .hbs file) :

```
<div class="nav left-menu">
    <div class="vertical-nav-line"> </div>
        <ul class="settings-menu">
            <li class="menu-general active"><a href="#" class="menu-general-link">{{i18n 'NavMenuGeneral'}}</a></li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you paste the `MyView` code, please?

Comment: Added MyView code + template code

Comment: Which version of Marionette are you using?

Comment: backbone 1.3.5 - 
backbone.marionette 2.4.3 - 
handlebars 4.0.5 - 
jquery 2.2.4 - 
jest 23.1.0

Comment: Is this code being run in browser or a NodeJS environment?

Comment: It runs in browser (and works fine, only the unit test crash)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a somewhat similar issue, so not sure this solution will work in your case. In my case, because the view itself didn't contain a `render` method I had to mock it in my test file.

```
import MyView from './MyView'

describe('test of my view', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    jest.spyOn(MyView.prototype, 'render').mockImplementation(jest.fn())
  })
  
  it('should render', function() {
    const myView = new MyView().render()
  })
})
```